# Powershell - IEX syntax woes

Tags: xml, powershell

After a couple of days of one step forward and two steps backward, I am still trying to get the output of one command and assign the various values back to variables. From the PS prompt, I can create an XML file, then successfully parse the data out with:

```
MediaInfo.exe --output=XML <path-to-file> >> .\info_out.xml
$xml = [xml](Get-Content .\info_out.xml)

$xml.Mediainfo.File.track[1]

$xml.Mediainfo.File.track[1].Duration --> 5mn 0s
$xml.Mediainfo.File.track[1].Format --> MPEG Video
$xml.Mediainfo.File.track[1].Format_profile --> 4:2:2@High
```

Now my issue is when trying to call the MediaInfo --output=XML switch with IEX or &.
I'd rather not have to write the XML to a file each time and would ideally like to use the xml function without having to write/read/cleanup an XML file time every time.

Here is an example of what I doing:

```
## Gather file info with MediaInfo (CLI) as XML
$tool = "C:\Program` Files\MediaInfoCLI\MediaInfo.exe"
$xmlswitch = "--Output=XML"
$Args = @("$tool", "$xmlswitch", "$filename" )

write-host "`n .............Testing.............. `n"
Write-Host "Executable: $tool"
Write-Host "XML switch: $xmlswitch"
Write-Host "Filename:   $filename"
Write-Host "Args: $Args `n `n"

$test = IEX $tool $xmlswitch $filename
write-host $test 
$test2 = IEX $Args
write-host $test2

exit 0
```

$test gives:

> Invoke-Expression : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '-->Output=XML'.
>   At C:\Program Files\GXFunpack\bin\mediainfo.v02.ps1:52 char:12
>   + $test = IEX <<<<  $tool $xmlswitch $filename
>      + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Invoke-Expression], ParameterBindingException
>      + FullyQualifiedErrorId : 
>   PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeExpressionCommand

$test2 gives:

> Invoke-Expression : Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'System.String' required by parameter 'Command'. Specified method is not supported.
>   At C:\Program Files\GXFunpack\bin\mediainfo.v02.ps1:54 char:13 + $test2 = IEX <<<<  $Args
>      + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Invoke-Expression], ParameterBindingException
>      + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgument,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeExpressionCommand

I have tried so many variations and deviations of syntax:

- $tool = "C:\Program Files\MediaInfoCLI\MediaInfo.exe"
- $tool = C:\"Program Files"\MediaInfoCLI\MediaInfo.exe
- IEX "$tool $xmlswitch $filename"
- "`-`-output=XML"
- and many, many more...

But every time it just spits back the next cryptic error.

Can anyone show me the errors of my way please?

Comment: The first one fails because you are passing in three strings when it wants one. The second fails because you are passing 1 array when it wants a string. what happens when you run `$test = Invoke-Expression "$tool $xmlswitch $filename"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
[xml]$xml = (MediaInfo.exe --output=XML <path-to-file>)
```

That should run your command and collect the output into the variable `$xml`.

Answer (score 2):

You probably just need the call invocation operator '&'.  You definitely don't need Invoke-Expression.

Try:

```
$test = & $tool $xmlswitch $filename
```

See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2011/06/03/invoke-expression-considered-harmful.aspx for more information on why you should avoid Invoke-Expression.